# How to use ISBLANK and AND operator

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I got the 2 cell, and maybe one or another has some value.
I another cell, I want to refer to a third on if the first cell AND the second cell is blank.

So here my try, unsuccesfull:

**=IF(AND(ISBLANK(H67),ISBLANK(I67));=G67;"")**

So the logical is: if H67 is blank AND I67 is blank, put the value of the cell H67, else put blank string in this cell.

Where i'm making a mistake?

Thkx!

Comment: You have a few syntax errors in your expression. The correct one would be `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(H67);ISBLANK(I67));G67;"")`. This is pretty basic so you should close your question.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu! It's work perfectly now...silly mistake! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Don't include the `=` in front of `G67`.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(H67);ISBLANK(I67)); G67; "")
```

Comment: Hi Diego, I still getting error. 
Actually if I use ISBLANK once it's ok, but maybe the comparison of AND i can't see where is the error.

Comment: @Thiago What is the error message? You can see that by hovering over the cell.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov Okay, just replace all the commas with semicolons. My response is updated.